# Quick Patch not creating Uninstallation

Tags: patch

I am using Installshield 2008 Premier edition, I am able to build the Quick patch successfully, and I am doing the following settings Under Quick patch project IDE, In **Installation Designer**; under **Patch Settings** **select General Information** Next select **Build Settings** and at the right hand side pane select the first tab named as **Common** and in that check the checkbox option Patch Uninstallation Allow Patch to be Uninstalled(Requires Windows Installer 3.0)

After setting this option; where do I find this uninstallation option whether it will display in add/remove program or will it create a shortcut in the start up menu under already installed parent product?

Comment: And also is it possible to write the Installscript for Quick Patch projects??? if Yes then how??

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of uninstalling patches. They are listed at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372104%28VS.85%29.aspx

About writting InstallScript - what exactly do you want to script in QuickPatch except patching files?

Comment: Greetings Fractalize
Thanks for the help..
i checked the link that you sent, on Uninstalling patches,but in my case installshied is creating Update.exe file where i double to run the patch and in Quick Patch project there is no option to put patch GUID as i found, how do i proceed further??

And about installscript before Quick Patch should run i want to call another c# .exe file that is my requirement then patch should contine after the .exe file...

Comment: Can you check GUID after the patch is installed? InstallShield stores it's vital data under C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information

Comment: Hi Fractalize i verified after running the patch Installshield is not storing GUID for QuickPatch, Installshield has stored GUID of the Setup not of QuickPatch!..

Comment: I am not sure about this QuickPatch, but it should keep it's files somewhere also.